PgpEncryptedDataList object is giving null
When I am trying to decrypt a PGP file with having valid phrase and private key, PgpEncryptedDataList object is giving null. Below is the code snippet:-
public static void DecryptStream(Stream inputStream, Stream privateKeyStream, string passPhrase, string outputFile, ILog log)
    {
      string output;
      try
      {
        PgpObjectFactory pgpFactory = new PgpObjectFactory(PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(inputStream));
        // find secret key
        PgpSecretKeyRingBundle pgpKeyRing = new PgpSecretKeyRingBundle(PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(privateKeyStream));

        PgpObject pgp = null;
        if (pgpFactory != null)
        {
          pgp = pgpFactory.NextPgpObject();
        }

        // the first object might be a PGP marker packet.
        PgpEncryptedDataList encryptedData = null;
        if (pgp is PgpEncryptedDataList)
        {
          encryptedData = (PgpEncryptedDataList)pgp;
        }
        else
        {
          encryptedData = (PgpEncryptedDataList)pgpFactory.NextPgpObject();
        }

        // decrypt
        PgpPrivateKey privateKey = null;
        PgpPublicKeyEncryptedData pubKeyData = null;
        foreach (PgpPublicKeyEncryptedData pubKeyDataItem in encryptedData.GetEncryptedDataObjects())
        {
          privateKey = FindSecretKey(pgpKeyRing, pubKeyDataItem.KeyId, passPhrase.ToCharArray());

          if (privateKey != null)
          {
            pubKeyData = pubKeyDataItem;
            break;
          }
        }

        if (privateKey == null)
        {
          throw new ArgumentException("Secret key for message not found.");
        }

        PgpObjectFactory plainFact = null;
        using (Stream clear = pubKeyData.GetDataStream(privateKey))
        {
          plainFact = new PgpObjectFactory(clear);
        }

        PgpObject message = plainFact.NextPgpObject();

        if (message is PgpCompressedData)
        {
          PgpCompressedData compressedData = (PgpCompressedData)message;
          PgpObjectFactory pgpCompressedFactory = null;

          using (Stream compDataIn = compressedData.GetDataStream())
          {
            pgpCompressedFactory = new PgpObjectFactory(compDataIn);
          }

          message = pgpCompressedFactory.NextPgpObject();
          PgpLiteralData literalData = null;
          if (message is PgpOnePassSignatureList)
          {
            message = pgpCompressedFactory.NextPgpObject();
          }

          literalData = (PgpLiteralData)message;
          using (Stream unc = literalData.GetInputStream())
          {
            output = IoHelper.GetString(unc);
          }

        }
        else if (message is PgpLiteralData)
        {
          PgpLiteralData literalData = (PgpLiteralData)message;
          using (Stream unc = literalData.GetInputStream())
          {
            output = IoHelper.GetString(unc);
          }
        }
        else if (message is PgpOnePassSignatureList)
        {
          throw new PgpException("Encrypted message contains a signed message - not literal data.");
        }
        else
        {
          throw new PgpException("Message is not a simple encrypted file - type unknown.");
        }


Need some suggestions on this issue
